# AWS Lambda halts halfway while executing a function

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, puppeteer

I tried to execute two functions imported from two different files on aws lambda:

```
const tag_test = require("./tag.js");
const login_logout = require("./login_logout.js");

exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
    await tag_test.tag();
    await login_logout.login();
    console.log("all tests done.");
}
```

The first function was executed fine, but while running the second function, lambda halted at one point and waited until the whole process timed out. I suspect it stopping right before `let browser` because on the console log, I can see `"opening up browser"` but not `"got browser"`.

```
module.exports.tag = async() => {
    console.log("starting test 2");
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-lambda');

    console.log("opening up browser");

    let browser = await puppeteer.getBrowser(
        '--no-sandbox',  
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--single-process'
        );
    console.log("got browser");
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    console.log("got page");

    //my test
    //...
```

}

Does anyone have any insight on what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

It's actually puppeteer-lambda's problem. Apparently you cannot open a browser, close it and then open it again on AWS lambda with puppeteer-lambda. I opened and later closed a browser in my first test and that's what made my second test stuck at `let browser`.

To solve this problem, I let the first test return the browser and pass it to the second test for reusing.

Answer (score 0):

increase lambda timeout. default is 3 seconds.

Comment: No matter how I change the timeout, it still keeps halting at the same position. So I don't think it's about time limit